# Is there any way to change Einstein Bot icon?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-einstein

I am trying to customize icon of `Einstein` bot but I am unable to customize it.
[This is a screenshot highlighting my problem](http://prntscr.com/n5vdr2).
Note:
I tried with all custom settings available in Einstein Bot as well as in org settings related to Einstein Bot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello Szymon,

Thanks for replying! I tried with all custom settings available in Einstein Bot as well as in org settings related to Einstein Bot.

Thanks

Comment: Add this information to your post please.